# How to pass callback from C# to C correctly?

Tags: c++

I am working with Unity and I need to pass callback delegate from C# unity script to `.dll`

There is a api `(MyApi.h)` that I have on `.dll` side

```
typedef void(__stdcall * FuncPtr) (const char * str);
static FuncPtr DebugLog = nullptr;

static void debug_in_unity(std::string message)
{
    if (DebugLog)
    {
        DebugLog(message.c_str());
    }
}

extern "C"
{
    DllExport void register_debug_callback(FuncPtr callback)
    {
        if (callback)
        {
            DebugLog = callback;
        }
    }
...
}
```

so, when I call `register_debug_callback` function from C# side I see that everything is ok and `DebugLog` assigned as expected.

Then in order to send my log message from `.dll` side to C# I need to call this function `debug_in_unity()`

So, I have another `myfile.cpp` file where I need to use this log function

```
#include "MyApi.h"

void MyClass::foo()
{
        std::string log = "HERE!!!";
        debug_in_unity(log);
}
```

So, everything looks fine, I have a global static method `debug_in_unity` and global func `DebugLog` that I assigned previously here `register_debug_callback`

But what actually is happen is - when I call this method `register_debug_callback` I see that I assigned `DebugLog` variable, but then when I call this method `debug_in_unity` I see that `DebugLog` is null. Looks like static variable is kind of not global like `MyApi.h` has instance of `DebugLog` and `myfile.cpp` has his own instance. I assume that it is a reason why I see assignment and then I see that the same value is null...

But how to use it properly? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking the one definition rule. You will need to have one translation unit (.c or .cpp file) defining `DebugLog`, and the header declaring it `extern`. Similarly your functions are also defined in multiple translation units.

MyApi.h

```
typedef void(__stdcall * FuncPtr) (const char * str);
extern FuncPtr DebugLog;

void debug_in_unity(std::string message);

extern "C"
{
    DllExport void register_debug_callback(FuncPtr callback);
    // ...
}
```

MyApi.cpp

```
#include "MyApi.h"
FuncPtr DebugLog = nullptr;

void debug_in_unity(std::string message)
{
    if (DebugLog)
    {
        DebugLog(message.c_str());
    }
}

extern "C"
{
    DllExport void register_debug_callback(FuncPtr callback)
    {
        if (callback)
        {
            DebugLog = callback;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```